# Determining angular momentum when given position and velocity in vector form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

```
Determine the angular momentum of a 60 g particle about the origin of
coordinates when the particle is at x = 2.3 m, y = -2.5 m, and it has
velocity vector v  = (1.5 i - 7.7k) m/s.

Lx = ?
Ly = ?
Lz = ?
```

I've tried a few ways of approaching this problem and I'm still getting the wrong answer.

Since `L=IW=mr^2(v/r)`, I first found `r` using the pythagoras theorem: r = sqrt((2.3)^2 + (2.5)^2) = 3.4. Plugging this in for `r` and using the magnitude of `v` as velocity, I get `(0.06)*(3.4^2)*(7.8/3.4) = 1.6`...but it's asking for the components of angular momentum, so this can't be right.

Next, I tried using the same value for `r`, but using just the x/i component of velocity -- `(0.06)*(3.4^2)*(1.5/3.4) = 0.306`...that's not right either.

I also tried using just the x element of position with just the x/i component of velocity, `(0.06)*(2.3^2)*(1.5/2.3) = 0.207`...also not correct.

What am I supposed to do?!

Comment: Use the definition, mate. $L=m\vec r\times \vec v$. How to calculate a cross product can be found all across the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).  But: Hint: use the *definition* of angular momentum.

Answer (score 2):

As CuriousOne inexplicably said in the comments, but not as a formal answer, you should use this equation: $$\vec{L}=m{\vec{r}}\times{\vec{v}}$$

This is the standard equation for angular momentum in vector form. Once you have your angular momentum vector, you can get the individual components. You can see how to take a cross product [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/linear-algebra-cross-product-introduction).

If you need to derive this equation, giving you the proof robs you of your education, so I will not do that.